# Grails 4 Security-ui plugin sending verification email, but not unlocking user

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I am trying to get my users to unlock in my postgreSQL database using the standard email verification using Grails, Security-core, Security-ui and mail.

Whenever I click the verification link in the email, it takes me to the main grails page for the app, as per the default post registration redirect, but it has not logged me on, and it has not updated the postgres database that I am using for persistence.

I suppose my main question is, what does the link in the verification email do, and what could I have done to cause this problem?

Here is my User class:

```
package com.anjg

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String username
    String password
    String email
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
    }

    static constraints = {
        password nullable: false, blank: false, password: true
        username nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
        email email: true, blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'Users'
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

Just incase I have done something silly when adding email to this domain class?

Thanks for any help given

Edit: So I have made sure that the Token being sent matches the url sent in the e-mail, and it does.

Comment: Have you checked the stacktrace or tried to debug? Could you share a PoC project? Hard to guess what actually might be failing in your project.